# Unix ipc server stops after one client stops

Tags: c, queue, ipc

I have a simple ipc program. The server generates a random number, and reads from stdin a number of clients. Each client sends random numbers to server , until they guess the server's number. When more than n/2 clients guess the number, the server stops. My problem is that the server stops after the first client guesses the number.

The server code :

```
int i=0; // the number of clients who guessed the number
srand(getpid()); 
numarul = rand() % 20;
printf("Numarul generat este %d \n",numarul);
for(;;){
   if(msgrcv(coadaId,&mesg,sizeof(Mesaj),1,0)<0) // read the mesage from queue
       printf("Eroare la receptionarea mesajului.");
   else{
       printf("Am primit numarul %d \n", mesg.nr); 
   if(mesg.nr == numarul){
                         i++; // is the number is guessed
                         printf("S-a ghicit numarul de la %d clienti \n",i);
                         mesg.val=1;} // msg.val = 1 if number is guessed
   mesg.tip=2; // change the message type
   msgsnd(coadaId,&mesg,sizeof(Mesaj),0); // send the msg.val . if 1 client stops
   mesg.val=0;
   if(i>n/2)break; // the loop ends when i is bigger than half number of clients
  }
  }
```

The client code:

```
mesg1.val=0;
srand(getpid()); 
while(mesg1.val!=1){
    mesg1.nr = rand() % 20; // generates number
    mesg1.tip=1;  // type = 1 
    if(msgsnd(coadaId,&mesg1,sizeof(Mesaj),0)<0) // sends message to queue
      printf("Eroare la trimiterea mesajului:");
    msgrcv(coadaId,&mesg1,sizeof(Mesaj),2,0); // reads message from the server
    if(mesg1.val==1)exit(0); // if the number is guessed quit 
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: In the server code, is `n` ever incremented based on the number of clients?

Comment: no, n is read in the server code with scanf, and remains the same

Answer (score 0):

Even though arithmetic operators take precedence over equality operators, it is still a good idea to use parentheses to improve clarity.

Answer (score 0):

`i` equals 0 before and equals 1 after the first client guesses the number. The server loop ends when `i>n/2`. As you say, this happens when `i` equals 1. From this follows that 0 ≤ n/2 < 1 ⇔ 0 ≤ n < 2, so, if `n` is an integer, it is 0 or 1. If you don't believe that, display `n` after the loop.